# Add new training face to EMGU CV recognizer (C#)

Tags: c#, emgucv

After the construction of the recognizer:

```
recognizer = new EigenObjectRecognizer(trainingImages, labels, 
             eigenDistanceThreshold, ref termCrit);
```

is it possible to add new images like:

```
recognizer.Add(image, label)
```

?

Having thousands of trained faces it's not a solution to rebuild (retrain) the recognizer after each new face.

Answer (score -1):

Use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261550/EMGU-Multiple-Face-Recognition-using-PCA-and-Paral) library, it acts like a helper library for the face recognition (eigen recognizer) class and provides an easy way to store training images.